# Is the equation given here an approximation of the actual venturimeter equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

> The manometer contains a liquid of density $ \rho_m$.
>
> [image]
>
> The speed $ v_1 $ of the liquid flowing through tube at a broad neck area to be measured from the equation of continuity (10.10).  the speed of consitrion becomes $ v_2 = \frac{A_1}{a} v_1$ . Then using bernoullis equation (10.12) for $h_1 = h_2$, we get:
> $$ P_1 + \frac{1}{2} \rho (v_1)^2 = P_2 + \frac{1}{2} \rho (v_1)^2( \frac{A}{a})^2$$
> So that
> $$ P_1 -P_2 = \frac{1}{2} \rho (v_1)^2 [ (\frac{A}{a})^2 -1]$$
> This pressure difference causes the fluid in U-tube connected at the narrow neck to rise in comparison to the other arm. The difference in height his seen as the pressure difference.
> $$P_1 - P_2 = \rho_m gh= \frac{1}{2} \rho (v_1)^2 [ (\frac{A}{a})^2 -1]$$
> Hence,
> $$v_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2ghρ_{m}}{ρ(\frac{A_{1}^2}{A_{2}^2}-1)}}$$
> where $ρ_{m}$ is the density of mercury and $ρ$ is the density of the liquid in the Venturimeter.

The problem I have with this derivation is the assumption that there is no pressure difference between fluid and venturi meter. I tried accounting for it in a derivation that I did myself and I got a different answer:

$$v_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2gh(\frac{ρ_{m}}{ρ}-1)}{(\frac{A_{1}^2}{A_{2}^2}-1)}}$$

where $ρ_{m}$ is the density of mercury and $ρ$ is the density of the liquid in the Venturimeter.

---

***My derivation:***

[image: My derivation of the Venturimeter equation]

1. ***Pressure equations:***

Pressures are equal in both arms at a height $h_1$ down each arm, and that pressure I label as P.Let Pressure at height $h_2$ down the right arm be $P^{'}$

We get  these three following equations:

$$P_A + ρgh_1 = P$$

so we can rewrite this as $$P_A = P - ρgh_1$$

similarly,

$$P_B + ρgh_2 = P^{'}$$

and $$P^{'} + ρ_{m}gh = P$$ where $h = h_{1} - h_{2}$

Using the above equations, we can isolate for $ P_A $ and $P_B$ in terms of pressure and height:

$$P_A = P - ρgh_1$$

$$P_B = P - ρgh_2 - ρ_{m}gh$$

---

2. ***Substituting the pressure equations into Bernoulli's equation***

Bernoulli's equation under the constant height of the pipe:

$$P_A + \frac{1}{2}ρv_{1}^{2} = P_B + \frac{1}{2}ρv_{2}^{2}$$

with substitutions of equations derived in the first section,

$$P - ρgh_1 + \frac{1}{2}ρv_{1}^{2} = P - ρgh_2 - ρ_{m}gh + \frac{1}{2}ρv_{2}^{2}$$

on simplifying we get

$$-ρgh_1 + \frac{1}{2}ρv_{1}^{2} = - ρgh_2 - ρ_{m}gh + \frac{1}{2}ρv_{2}^{2}$$

And with some extra algebra,

$$(ρ - ρ_{m})gh = \frac{1}{2}ρ(v_{1}^{2} - v_{2}^{2})$$

Here $v_{2}$ can be equated to $\frac{A_{1}v_{1}}{A_{2}}$ (from the Principle of continuity)

this then gives us:

$$(ρ - ρ_{m})gh = \frac{1}{2}ρv_{1}^{2}(1 - \frac{A_{1}^{2}}{A_{2}^{2}})$$

Upon re-arranging, we get:

$$v_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2gh(\frac{ρ_{m}}{ρ}-1)}{(\frac{A_{1}^2}{A_{2}^2}-1)}}$$

---

**The problem:**

What I did differently was that I considered even the pressure difference due to the liquid in between the mercury and that in the Venturimeter. After that, I just applied Bernoulli's equation...

My question is whether the derivation in my book has without mentioning taken an approximation that $ρ <<<ρ_{m}$? Because doing so yields the right equation, but I am not sure if that is it or whether I have gone wrong somewhere else...

**Extra bit of confusion:**  Say you take the densities of the 2 liquids (in this case equal to mercury) as equal, in case of the equation derived in the book, you get the same equation as you would get in case of an open (to air) manometer based Venturimeter as shown [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Venturi5.svg) which gives a non zero velocity value. But doing so in my equation gives me a velocity value equal to zero. So are both equations still correct? If not which one is wrong and what about it is wrong? –

---

**References:**
**Page -260, Ncert Physics Class-11 part-2**

---

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are correct in principle. I haven't checked your derivation, but it looks plausible. Mostly, the pressure difference in the column from the gas is considered negligible, so the pressure at 1 is the same as the pressure at the top of the mercury and the same for 2.

Comment: @DrXorile I see, but that raises another question, say you take the densities of the 2 liquids (in this case equal to mercury) as equal, in case of the book derived equation, you get the same equation as you would get in case of an open (to air) manometer based Venturimeter as shown [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Venturi5.svg) which gives a  non zero in value. But doing so in my equation gives me a velocity value equal to zero. So are both equations still correct? If not which one is wrong and what about it is wrong?

Comment: The two models are subtly different. Your version has a total height that is the same on both sides, so it breaks down when the fluids are the same density

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equations are correct. The density of the fluid under test is assumed to be much less than that of mercury and is neglected.

In the case of the open air manometer based venturimeter, the fluid under test is assumed to be much denser than air and thus the density of air is neglected.

If you used water in the loop and tried to test with an oil flow you'd definitely need to account for both densities to get an accurate measurement. (This should actually be a precise way to measure low flow except I think the effects of surface energies might reduce accuracy)

If you tried to use two fluids with the same density there would be nothing preventing the fluid in the loop from flowing up into the flow path. So there would be no steady state, it would be like you have an infinite height so the velocity would be undefined rather than 0.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think the last part where you mention the flow would no longer be steady, that is something that I didn't think of, thanks for mentioning it. It makes a lot more sense now!