# Venturi Meter and Pascal's principle

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

When trying to understand how the venturimeter works, I got stucked with the following affirmation:

> Then, we have the equation $P_1 = P_2 + \rho g d$

[image]

Where $d$ is the distance between the two points, $P_1$ and $P_2$ being the respective pressures, and $\rho$ is the blue liquid's density (which also fills the entire tube).  As I understand, that equation follows from Pascal's Principle.

Here's the problem: As far as I know, Pascal's principle only applies to Fluids at rest, but the Fluid in the tube has velocity $V > 0$, which  is not static. So, my question is: Why can we apply Pascal's principle here?. If Pascal's principle is indeed the case, how do you derive that equation in the case of fluids in motion and how do I determine when Pascal's principle can be applied? (Because not all fluids in motion obbey this law)

Obs: This formula has been derived [in this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/580249/is-the-equation-given-here-an-approximation-of-the-actual-venturimeter-equation) and impied in *Halliday, Renick. Fundamentals of Physics, 14th Chapter, 10th edition* in the problems section 14-7, problem 65. This [video](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/580249/is-the-equation-given-here-an-approximation-of-the-actual-venturimeter-equation) also touches this topic.

Comment: Something is wrong with your equation.  Is the blue liquid water?  Is the silver liquid mercury?  With two liquids involved, there are two different densities to worry about.

Comment: To be clear: There are two fluids involved in the whole problem. However, note that Pascal principle is being used only in the red column of  (lets suppose) water. Why it does not matter that there are two fluids in the artifact? Because I'm just considering one part of the whole venturimeter (namely, again, the left red column of water, and applying possibly pascal's principle to that reduced system)

Comment: Maybe what's confusing you is the fact that I didn't specify whose density is $\rho$. Made an update to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:-Pascal's principle can NOT be applied on the fluid below the tube because the interpretation of Pascal's law which says pressure is same everywhere in a static liquid holds only under zero gravity condition unlike the case of a venturimeter.But if we interpret Pascal's law as given in Encyclopaedia Brittanica which says "  a pressure change in one part is transmitted without loss to every portion of the fluid and to the walls of the container " then Pascal's Law will hold under all situations but it has nothing to do with our current derivation. So we cannot say that this relation is derived from Pascal's Law.**

For any liquid column at rest the pressure at a depth h is h$\rho$g. Here the liquid  in the pipe may be moving but the liquid in the connected manometer( which is the u tube connected to pipe) is at rest.So here this formula is applicable.For a more elaborate explanation:

Here the liquid in the U column is at rest while the liquid in the pipe is moving.So the net force on the liquid in the column is zero .This liquid faces a downward force due to P$_2$ which is  equal to P$_2 A$ and an upward force due to P$_1$ equal to P$_1$A as shown in the picture .Now the net resultant of these two must equal the weight of the liquid column. If the length of the column is d and density id $\rho$ the weight is Volume$\times$density$\times$g i.e dA$\rho$g.

So $$ P_1A - P_2A = dA\rho g$$ or
$$P_1 - P_2 = d\rho g$$ or
$$ P_1 = P_2 + d\rho g$$
[image]

Comment: Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Mobius, with all due respect, I note the following: "d" is shown as the height of the water column (assuming light blue represents water) in the left leg of the manometer and it is also shown as the dimension of the throat of the venturi meter.  In addition, no accounting is given of the difference in height of the mercury in the legs of the manometer (assuming that dark blue represents mercury).  Since there are two different densities involved in these fluids, the equation $P_1=P_2 + d \rho g$ is quite ambiguous.

Comment: @Möbius, I completely agree that Pascal principle can be applied on the fluid below the tube, but my question is not about how to derive pressure differences inside a Venturimeter (as I am already aware of them), but rather it seems that the derivation that other people are applying seems to violate Pascal's Law.

Comment: In this sense, you are comparing pressures at two different heights which happen to have statis fluid between them. My problem is that other people seem to compare pressure P1 with pressure in the middle of the tube, since Bernoulli's Equation must be applied.

Comment: Well ,to apply Bernoulli we assume pressure is uniform at all points on a cross-section of the fluid so the pressure at the middle of the tube is same as the pressure near the opening of the manometer. As for your other doubt about pascal's law, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Let me know what you think of it

Comment: Ok @Möbius, I think it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Alexp9,

this isn't intended to be an answer, but I need more room than I can get in a comment.  I looked at your link that was tied to "in this question" in your original post.  In the part where the author derived the pressure across the manometer, he wrote the following:

"This pressure difference causes the fluid in U-tube connected at the narrow neck to rise in comparison to the other arm. The difference in height his seen as the pressure difference.
$P1−P2=ρ_mgh$
...

where ρm is the density of mercury and ρ is the density of the liquid in the Venturimeter".

I did this EXACT experiment when studying for my B.S. in chemical engineering some years back.  If the fluid flowing through the venturi is something like a gas with a very low density, the equation is correct.  However, if the fluid flowing through the manometer is something like water, which has a relatively high density, a correction must be made whereby the difference in density between mercury and the flowing fluid is the correct value.  This means that the equation should have read

$P1−P2=(ρ_m - \rho _f)gh$

where $\rho _f$ can be ignored if it is much smaller than the density of mercury.  For water flowing through the venturi, with a mercury manometer measuring the pressure difference, the density of the water cannot be ignored, so the rest of the derivation in your link is questionable.

Comment: Thanks for your time David. It is a missfortune that you quoted the part of the question I didn't want to discuss about. My choose of terminology does not help either. Please note that my P1 and P2 are his PA and PB, respectively. Just read the section "My derivation"  in that post. Also, for clarity, I will made an update on this question in 12 hours, to avoid more confusion

Comment: @alexp9, note that the part of the question that I quoted is directly related to the picture and equation that you posted.  Also note that in the picture that you posted, you should start measuring at the top of the left part of the manometer tube.  Starting a measurement in a flowing stream and using that for a manometer calculation has never been done as far as I know.

Comment: @alexp9, based on your comment to Mobius, if you want to see a derivation for how to calculate the pressure difference across a venturi using a manometer, please post another question asking this exact thing.  I (and no doubt others) already have a derivation for this measurement.

Comment: At the moment I don't need the derivation. I just wanted to know whether it was possible to apply a formula in a derivation. However, after some time thinking, I believe I have come to a conclusion, and it was thanks to your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my poor english. My native language is french.

Strictly speaking, you can only apply the result of statics (what you call "Pascal's principle") for the part of the fluid at rest.

For the moving part of the fluid, there is a theorem, applicable here, which indicates that, for a unidirectional non-viscous flow, the pressure varies as in static in a direction perpendicular to that of the flow. This theorem is easy to prove by projecting Euler's equation perpendicular to the flow.

Finally, it remains to prove the continuity of the pressure through the hole which serves as a junction between the fluid at rest and the fluid which flows. The proof of this point is not simple because it requires a close look at what is happening there.